# How to convert JSON String to Object MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, type-conversion, migrate

I am using golang migrate library for MongoDB migration. Update here is based on $aggregate functions of MongoDB. In my base there are some String fields which store JSON objects, I need to convert them to Objects(nested structure). I can't find Object arg in $convert function as well as special convert function(like $toLong). Is there any way to do such conversion?

Comment: You may unmarshal the JSON string into `interface{}` (or a map), and use that.

Comment: icza, I'd like to use mongodb features for this task to make all migrations uniform

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.